# composer create-project - command donot work

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I have my project on github containing composer.json in the root directory.
This is how my composer.json code looks like:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/projectname",
    "description": "My first Composer project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "John Deo",
            "email": "johndeo@demo.com"
        }
    ],
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.3"        
    }
}
```

I had defined/submited my package on packagist.org.

Now when I try to get the project in my localhost using `composer create-project - commands`  one of its work and another do not work.

```
1. composer create-project -s dev vendor/projectname  >> WORKS

2. composer create-project vendor/projectname >> DO NOT WORK
```

Can someone please tell why the second command does not work.
What am I missing or doing wrong?
Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a stable version of `vendor/projectname`. In git, a tag (without flag) is a stable version and branches are dev versions. So you have to tag a release (e.g. `git tag 1.0.0`).